# Convert SOAP Envelope to String (OpenSAML)

Tags: string, soap, opensaml, envelope

I am trying to generate a SOAP fault and return the SOAP envelope as a string using opensaml library.
 Here is my code.

```
XMLObjectBuilderFactory builderFactory = org.opensaml.xml.Configuration.getBuilderFactory();

SOAPObjectBuilder<Envelope> envelopeSOAPObjectBuilder = (SOAPObjectBuilder<Envelope>) builderFactory.getBuilder(
        Envelope.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
Envelope envelope = envelopeSOAPObjectBuilder.buildObject();

SOAPObjectBuilder<Fault> faultSOAPObjectBuilder = (SOAPObjectBuilder<Fault>) builderFactory.getBuilder(
        Fault.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
Fault fault = faultSOAPObjectBuilder.buildObject();

SOAPObjectBuilder<FaultCode> faultCodeSOAPObjectBuilder = (SOAPObjectBuilder<FaultCode>) builderFactory.getBuilder(
        FaultCode.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
FaultCode faultCode = faultCodeSOAPObjectBuilder.buildObject();

SOAPObjectBuilder<FaultString> faultStringSOAPObjectBuilder = (SOAPObjectBuilder<FaultString>) builderFactory.getBuilder(
        FaultString.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
FaultString faultString = faultStringSOAPObjectBuilder.buildObject();

SOAPObjectBuilder<Body> bodySOAPObjectBuilder = (SOAPObjectBuilder<Body>) builderFactory.getBuilder(
        Body.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
Body body = bodySOAPObjectBuilder.buildObject();

fault.setCode(faultCode);
fault.setMessage(faultString);

body.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(fault);
envelope.setBody(body);
```

Can Anyone sugget me way to convert the soap envelope<> to string ?

Answer (score 0):

The soap envelope can be converted to a string with the use of import org.opensaml.xml.util.XMLHelper;

```
 System.out.println((XMLHelper.prettyPrintXML(marshallObject(envelope))));
```

This didn't work properly earlier, as the way I have create the faultcode and fault string is incomplete.

After adding the following lines before fault.setCode(faultCode) the code worked.

```
 faultCode.setValue(FaultCode.CLIENT);
 faultString.setValue(FaultString.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_LOCAL_NAME);
```